# Is there a way via API to track triggered builds in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

With the classic build pipelines and classic triggers, it was easy enough to track builds that were triggered by completion of other builds by just polling for builds requested by the same user.

Now, with resource triggers, the requested by property switching to the build service account instead of the original author of the triggering commit.

I have been going through the documentation to try and find another way to see triggered builds from the original build ID but have not found anything.

There is an "Associated Pipelines" tab on the build summary page that at least has the pipelines containing the triggered builds, but I cannot find anything to get that by API either.

Comment: Maybe you could add the links to the documentation that you used so far?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can first call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get all the running build pipelines in the definition, and then use the powershell script to loop check the **id** in the parameter **triggeredByBuild** in the request body in the specific build so that you can see triggered builds from the original buildId.

Note: The id marked in the attachment is the original buildId that triggered another build pipeline.

[image]

Comment: The issue is that there's no way to even find that triggering pipeline. I need to go the other way. From the triggeredByBuild, I need to find the resultant triggered build.

Comment: Currently, it is impossible to find the resultant triggered build directly from the original build pipeline. Only use the powershell script to loop check the id in the parameter triggeredByBuild in the request body in the specific build.

About this feature, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.